# NSString is integer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

How to check if the content of a NSString is an integer value? Is there any readily available way?

There got to be some better way then doing something like this:

```
- (BOOL)isInteger:(NSString *)toCheck {
  if([toCheck intValue] != 0) {
    return true;
  } else if([toCheck isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could use the `-intValue` or `-integerValue` methods. Returns zero if the string doesn't start with an integer, which is a bit of a shame as zero is a valid value for an integer.

A better option might be to use [`[NSScanner scanInt:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsscanner/1410914-scanint?language=objc) which returns a `BOOL` indicating whether or not it found a suitable value.

Comment: Right on! A simple [[NSScanner scannerWithString:value] scanInt:nil] will check if "value" has an integer value.
Thanks!

Comment: What value will integerValue return if the string is empty?

Comment: @ASalcedo Presumably you can't rely on the contents if the method returns NO.

Comment: Note `-[NSScanner scanInt:]` returns true for @"00ab" as well -- use `-[NSScanner isAtEnd]` from Steven Green's answer below, or convert into NSNumber (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber?rq=1) to handle such cases

Answer (score 45):

Something like this:

```
NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:toCheck]; 
int val; 
return [scan scanInt:&val] && [scan isAtEnd];
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858584/383919) from @kevbo, this will check for integers >= 0:

```
if (fooString.length <= 0 || [fooString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"This is not a positive integer");
}
```

A swift version of the above:

```
func getPositive(incoming: String) -> String {
    if (incoming.characters.count <= 0) || (incoming.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet) != nil) {
        return "This is NOT a positive integer"
    }
    return "YES! +ve integer"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget numbers with decimal point!!!

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *carSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];
BOOL isNumber = [[subBoldText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:carSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getPositive(input: String) -> String {
    if (input.count <= 0) || (input.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) != nil) {
        return "This is NOT a positive integer"
    }
    return "YES! integer"
}
```

Update @coco's answer for Swift 5