# How to add two textField value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to take two textfields values and add the values and show them into another textField.

How to  do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber), then add the two NSNumbers.

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:ftext];
NSNumber * myNumber2 = [f numberFromString:ftext2];

float out = [myNumber floatValue] + [myNumber floatValue];
[f autorelease];
```

-dan

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `floatValue` method on `NSString` so you can also do something like:

```
float sum = [textField1.text floatValue] + [textField2.text floatValue];
```

Which is a little more concise.