# Problem when converting NSString to NSNumber in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, core-plot, nsnumber

I am having problem when converting string (YaxisData) to NSNumber. I have to return a NSNumber for Core-plot to get the graph done but its not working. Here's the sample code

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[YaxisData objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]];
return num;
```

}

num returns junk data such as -1 or 993494949494 but when I log the double value of number, it prints the correct value. I am not able to return this double value as the function signature requires only the NSNumber to be returned.

```
NSLog(@"Number: %f", [num doubleValue]);
```

I am stuck here and would really appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: What is `YaxisData` and where does it come from?

Comment: What am I missing? Three input parameters, none of them is used, but another variable that we know nothing about.

Comment: @Franci Penov: YaxisData is an array which is storing numbers as strings.

@Eiko: This is a core-plot method for getting the data for each row so that the graph can be plotted. What the method does is least important. All I want to know is the correct way of converting an array of string into an NSNumber.

Answer (score 1):

Would this give a better result somehow?

```
NSString *aString = [YaxisData objectAtIndex:index];
NSLog(@"%@", aString);
double value = [aString doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%f", value);
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value];
NSLog(@"%@", number);
```

If not, could you show the results of the *NSLog()*'s?

I know that in practice it seems the same code, yet one might not be so sure that *-objectAtIndex:* always returns a string. It might be a localization issue as well (commas and dots for decimal separator might get mixed up, this would definitely mess up your results. In case of a localization issue, check the following link:

[How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber/1448875#1448875)