# Correctly convert NSString to NSnumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I can't figure out why it's not working, I have a NSString which I need to convert to NSNumber (to save it to Core Data)
e.g

```
NSLog(stringNum);
```

returns 1

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:stringNum];
[f release];

NSLog(@"myNumber = %i", myNumber);
```

returns 120882496 or something like this

What am I missing?
Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

Comment: @Björn: This is obviously where he got the code from, but his problem is another one, namely the NSLog-error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's now an object, not an integer, therefore you must use `%@` in NSLog, not `%i`.

Answer (score 3):

`myNumber` is an object, so the format should be

```
@"myNumber = %@"
```