# How to do string related problem

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am making a binary to decimal number converter on iphone. having some problem when i trying to take each single digit from a number and do calculation. I tried char, characterAtIndex but they all failed to do calculation or i got the syntax completely wrong. Can anyone show me how to do such cast or there is an easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is getting numbers from strings?

The easiest way to get an integer from a character is to use the ascii table, like this:

```
NSString *stringOfNums = @"15";
char c;
int num;
for (int i = 0; i < [stringOfNums length]; ++i) {
    c = [stringOfNums characterAtIndex:i];
    num = c - 48; // 0 is 48 in ascii table
    printf("\nchar is %c and num is %d", c, num);
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you can validate on a char-by-char basis that each falls in a range of 48 through 57, the ascii digits.

Or you could do the conversion in one step using NSNumberFormatter, as described here: [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

As for the binary-decimal conversion, does your formula work on paper? Get that right first.