# Convert a number with a comma into a number with point. (Cocoa Touch)

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I'm trying to code a calculator with XCode, but then I saw that Numbers with a comma are just cutted of after the comma.

I am getting the Numbers with this code out of the textfield.

```
-(IBAction)Additionbutton:(id)sender{

NSString *firstString = field1.text;
NSString *secondString = field2.text;
float num1;
float num2;
float output;
num1 = [firstString floatValue];
num2 = [secondString floatValue];
output = num1 + num2
Solutionfield.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",output] ;
```

Is it possible to set the calculation that way, that it is able to handle points AND commas or do I have to convert them and if so, how can I do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Solutionfield.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",output]; you try in this way ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use: NSNumberFormatter

[How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber/1448875#1448875)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same thing this morning, following solution worked for me:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[yourFloatAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" ] floatValue]];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *formattedNumber;
formattedNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:aNumber];
NSLog(@"formattedNumber: %@", formattedNumber);
```

Obviously not the most efficient solution possible. It works, but if you have some time I strongly suggest you to have a look at [NSNumberFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumberFormatter)