# How can I check if the string doesn't contain a valid numerical value in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, double

I am doing the comparison:

```
 else if([change doubleValue] == 0 && indexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
```

how can I check for the case where [change doubleValue] doesn't return anything?

Comment: How can it not return anything?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't return anything"? Do you mean if `change` doesn't understand the `doubleValue` message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to compare floating point numbers with the `==`-operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way the `doubleValue` method goes without returning anything. The least value you can check for is `0`. The following are the cases the *doubleValue* returns 0.

1. The `string` doesn't contain a valid numerical value.
2. The `string` is `nil`.
3. The `string` actually contains `@"0"`.

**Checking for a valid number**
Use NSPredicate to test if the string contains a numerical value.

```
NSString *str = @"sfas";
NSString *regx = @"(-){0,1}(([0-9]+)(.)){0,1}([0-9]+)";
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regx];
BOOL isAValidNumber = [test evaluateWithObject:str];
```

Comment: How can I check if the string doesn't contain a valid numerical value?

Comment: Use a NSPredicate test. Updated the answer.

Comment: What if the user's in a locale where `,` is used as the decimal separator?  Using an `NSNumberFormatter` is the superior option.

Comment: @Dave DeLong, Yeah. That's a good point. For that reason you down voted this answer? I don't think that is a major reason for this answer to be down voted?

Comment: @Dave DeLong, My answer is just an simple example. You have to tweak to fit your needs. You should not expect an answer to be 100% perfect.

Comment: Also negative numbers will fail with this example predicate.

Comment: Your new regex recognizes "-." (assuming you meant "\." in the middle and not "."). It requires numbers to have a decimal point, so you can't recognize "42". It also requires numbers to have a negative sign. It also won't recognize scientific notation ("4.2e1"), or numbers grouped into thousands (1,234.5 or 1.234,5). I down voted because while using a regex can work, it's extremely error-prone. Plus, the Foundation framework already has code that does this for you. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

see `NSScanner`

---