# How to convert NSString into NSNumber

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios4, ios5

How can I convert NSString into NSNumber. For ex. I have @"0100", I want to convert it into NSNumber and as per my requirements, the result should be 0100 not 100. Is there any way to achieve this or I have to use NSString instead on NSNumber

Comment: How exactly can a number be 0100?

Comment: Use an NSNumberFormatter as described in this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber

Comment: As an integral number "0100" = 100.  I don't get it

Comment: @Alan Thanks, but I have tried this but if we pass "042", then the result would be 42 instead of 042. This think, I have to use the NSString for storing the values, instead of NSNumber as it denotes 042 as 42. For achieving my requirements, I need 042 as result, so i think only NSString is the solution

Comment: Are you maybe trying to store .0100?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I believe you are right in your conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by you need a NSNumber with value 0100, instead of 100?  Does it make a difference that doesn't agree with integer arithmetic?  If so, then how, and if not, then do you mean that you have to output the number at some later time with the leading 0?

If so, then use the correct formatter while outputting the number, and don't worry about it before.

If you need to store numeric characters exactly then use a NSString.  Validate it before accepting or using it.  Turning it into a number is *not* what you want to or mean to do.

Comment: I want user to enter numeric only (passcode), and I want to compare it with already stored value. The already soted value can be either NSString or NSSNumber (decided at runtime), so I want the exact output. I think, I have to go for NSString only

Comment: @iHS you don't need to convert it to number for that.

Comment: Thanks alot. Looks like, NSString is only the correct option in this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the following which will solve your problem. You can easily convert your string with int & display as you want.

```
NSString *str=@"0100";
    int myInt = [str intValue];
    NSLog(@"Int:%i",myInt);
Result  Int:100
```

I hope, this will solve you problem. Thanks.