# converting large number from NSString to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I know I am probably missing something pretty basic here, but I am trying to convert a number entered on a UITextField from a NSString into a NSNumber as follows:

```
self.currentServer.port = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[addressPortTextField.text doubleValue]];
NSLog(@"Port: %@ / %@", addressPortTextField.text, self.currentServer.port);
```

The number in self.currentServer.port is 50000

The NSLog shows the following:

Port: 50000 / -15536

I don't get what I am doing wrong here?  I've tried with doubleValue, intValue, integerValue.

* I found the Problem ****

self.currentServer.port is a coredata field of type Integer16.  50000 is to large for that field size, I updated the database to Integer32 and all is well now.

---

Comment: Try using NSNumberFormatter, as [this answer][1] suggests.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber

Comment: Why do you say that `self.currentServer.port` is 50000 when it is printing `-15536`? What makes you think it has 50000? If I do `NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[@"50000" intValue]]);` it correctly prints 50000

Comment: You say you tried `intValue` and it didn't work? Are you sure? This should work: `[NSNumber numberWithInt:[addressPortTextField.text intValue]]`

Comment: The self.currentServer.port field is a core database field defined as NSNumber elsewhere. I tried both numberWithInt and IntValue as well as numberWithInteger and integerValue. No difference. The code works with smaller numbers, like 8080 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
 self.currentServer.port = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[addressPortTextField.text doubleValue]];
```

and can be the source of the problem. You are converting the text to double and then saving the value in an int. If you try:

```
self.currentServer.port = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[addressPortTextField.text integerValue]];
```

it is also important how have you defined the currentServer.port.

Comment: To be exact, you should use `numberWithInteger` and `integerValue` or `numberWithInt` and `intValue`. The former uses the `NSInteger` type, the latter uses the `int` type. It doesn't matter on iOS, there they are both 32bit signed integers, but on MacOS, int is 32bit and long is 64bit. (If you have a 64bit CPU)

Answer (score 0):

`self.currentServer.port = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[addressPortTextField.text doubleValue]];`

Note that you are getting a double value from the text field, is that really what you want?  Then calling numberWithInt on the double value.

What you probable want is 
`self.currentServer.port = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[addressPortTextField.text integerValue]];`