# Accurately Converting NSString to GLFloat - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, nsstring, floating-point

Say I have some vertice values which I am reading into my app as a NSString :

-7501.6 -6198.2 834.939 -5547.66 -6348.32 2122.65

The values in the source are always 6 figures in length.

I need to pass these exact values to OpenGL. If I try to cast as a float (using NSString floatValue) then, as expected, I get an approximate value for each float due to the inexact nature of a float :

-7501.600098, -6198.200195, 834.939026 -5547.660156, -6348.319824, 2122.649902

Can anyone suggest a way that I can get these values into OpenGL and retain their exact initial integrity ?

Thank you.

Comment: But even OpenGL will be using floats/doubles. If these values cannot be represented exactly as floating-point values, then you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this: [NSString to NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448875/644629) could help.

Answer (score -1):

See 'Getting Numeric Values' paragraph from NSString Documentation (Apple).

[str floatValue];
[str doubleValue];