# [__NSCFDictionary enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101918a10'

Tags: ios, xcode, json, core-data

I am reading jason data from my json file, and i am successful in printing the NSarray type arraytsik, now when i try to loop through the arraytsik using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock it's giving me outup or array with error

> ```
>  2012-12-17 16:59:04.711 tsikzoeMig[6416:303] here i am printing the array {
>     tsik =     (
>                 {
>             author = 2;
>             authorName = fgfg;
>             dateSubmitted = "2012-08-19 00:00:00";
>             dictionaryType = 1;
>             id = 1;
>             word = fgdf;
>             wordDef = fdgdfg;
>         },
>                 {
>             author = 2;
>             authorName = "\U0f51\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f40\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f5a\U0f72\U0f42\U0f0b\U0f58\U0f5b\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0d";
>             dateSubmitted = "2012-08-19 00:00:00";
>             dictionaryType = 1;
>             id = 2;
>             word = "\U0f21\U0f20\U0f24\U0f20\U0f56\U0f66\U0f7c\U0f0d";
>             wordDef = "\U0f56\U0f66\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f66\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f5e\U0f7a\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f92\U0fb2\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f41\U0fb1\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f42\U0fb1\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f58\U0f72\U0f44\U0f0c\U0f0d";
>         }
>     );
> }
> 2012-12-17 16:59:04.712 tsikzoeMig[6416:303] -[__NSCFDictionary enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> ```
>
> 0x102114700
>       2012-12-17 16:59:04.713 tsikzoeMig[6416:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFDictionary enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x102114700'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (
>         0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1190a6 **exceptionPreprocess + 198
>         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a2963f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
>         2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1af6ea -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
>         3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1075ce __*forwarding*** + 414
>         4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a1073b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
>         5   tsikzoeMig                          0x0000000100001cd3 main + 851
>         6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8acd97e1 start + 0
>         7   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>       )
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>       (lldb)

my main.m code is here

```
//  main.m

#import "TsikzoeE.h"
static NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel()
{
    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;
    if (model != nil) {
        return model;
    }

    NSString *path = @"tsikzoe";
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"momd"]];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return model;
}

static NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext()
{
    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        return context;
    }

    @autoreleasepool {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

        NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

        NSString *path = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments][0];
        path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];

        NSError *error;
        NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error];

        if (newStore == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        }
    }
    return context;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Custom code here...
        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        NSError* err = nil;

        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tsikzoe" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* arraytsik = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]options:kNilOptions error:&err];

        // array outputing here to check

        NSLog(@"here i am printing the array %@",arraytsik);


        [arraytsik enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


           TsikzoeE *tsikz = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TsikzoeE"inManagedObjectContext:context];
            tsikz.id = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
            tsikz.dictionaryType=[obj objectForKey:@"dictionaryType"];
            tsikz.word=[obj objectAtIndex:3];
            tsikz.wordDef=[obj objectForKey:@"wordDef"];
            tsikz.author=[obj objectForKey:@"author"];
            tsikz.authorName=[obj objectForKey:@"authorName"];
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TsikzoeE"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (TsikzoeE *tsikz in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"word: %@", tsikz.word);

            NSLog(@"wordDef: %@", tsikz.wordDef);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

my json content is

```
{"tsik":[{"id":1,"dictionaryType":1,"word":"fgdf","wordDef":"fdgdfg","dateSubmitted":"2012-08-19 00:00:00","author":2,"authorName":"fgfg"},{"id":2,"dictionaryType":1,"word":"༡༠༤༠བསོ།","wordDef":"བསོ་བསོ་ཞེས་པའི་སྒྲའི་ཁྱད་པར་གྱི་མིང༌།","dateSubmitted":"2012-08-19 00:00:00","author":2,"authorName":"དུང་དཀར་ཚིག་མཛོད།"}]}
```

my TsikzoeE.h code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface TsikzoeE : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * author;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * authorName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * dictionaryType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * word;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * wordDef;


@end
```

tsikzoeE.m code

```
  //
//  TsikzoeE.m


#import "TsikzoeE.h"


@implementation TsikzoeE

@dynamic author;
@dynamic authorName;
@dynamic dictionaryType;
@dynamic id;
@dynamic word;
@dynamic wordDef;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON data contain a *dictionary* (with one key "tsik") and not an *array*.

The following should work better:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSArray *arraytsik = [dict objectForKey:@"tsik"];
```

There seems also to be a problem inside the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` block: `obj` is a dictionary here, so

```
tsikz.word=[obj objectAtIndex:3];
```

does not work. Perhaps you meant

```
tsikz.word=[obj objectForKey:@"word"];
```

*Remark:* You could also consider to save the managed object context *after* the loop has completed instead of saving it for each item added.

Comment: hi martin now i am trying the json from url, such as NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/tsikzoe/json.php"];
        
        NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] options:0 error:&err];
        NSArray *arrayTsikzoe =[rootDictionary objectForKey:@"tsik"];
        NSLog(@"arraytsikzoe is %@",arrayTsikzoe);                                   But the array prints null. please help me in that

Comment: @user1838612: What is the contents of `rootDictionary`?

Comment: hi martin i have pasted the latest error and output and changed the main.m file as well, please help me to find the error, i am getting error print properly, but there is one error relating to type at tsikz.dictionaryType=[obj objectForKey:@"dictionaryType"]; may be dictionaryType is numeric thats why

Comment: @user1838612: If `[obj objectForKey:@"dictionaryType"]` returns a string then you have to convert that to `NSNumber`, see for example  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448875/1187415.

Comment: thanks martin, it worked actually i am trying to make one tibetan ios dictionary with multilanguage, i have already on as webbased http://tsikzoe.net thanks for your help