# How do I get Scientific Notation in a text field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to get this text field in my app to display in scientific notation after 8 characters are entered in (sort of like the built-in Calculator App). I've got everything working right, except when it's supposed to show in scientific notation, it just shows '0.0'.

What is wrong with my code?

```
NSString *current;
NSString *str = (NSString*)[sender currentTitle]; //sender is in the method header
if([current isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    current = str;
} else if (current.length < 8){
    current = [current stringByAppendingString:str];
} else {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    current = [formatter stringFromNumber:(NSNumber*)current];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just cast an `NSString` to an `NSNumber`. Use `doubleValue` to convert an `NSString` to a double:

```
current = [formatter stringFromNumber:@([current doubleValue])];
```

Or you can use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert strings to numbers as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448875/1489997)

Comment: Now, using the code you gave me, nothing happens after 8 characters are inserted.

Comment: If you step through the code with the debugger, do you end up in the final `else` block?

Comment: @coryginsberg: Check your if-statements. You probably should test `str`, not `current`.