# NSString To NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, int, nsnumber

So this problem has been perplexing me for way too long.  I have a `UIAlertView` with a `textField` in it, and I need the value of the `textField` as an `NSNumber`.  But everything I try gives me random strings of numbers.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
int i = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text intValue];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text integerValue]];    


int number = [[dict objectForKey:@"integer"] intValue];

NSLog(@"text = %@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);


NSString *alertText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text];


NSNumber *number = @([alertText intValue]);

NSString *string = @"54";
NSNumber *number = @([string intValue]);

NSLog(@"here we are: %i", number);
```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber

Comment: I saw that before asking.  But when I ran that code, I got: `159348080 `

Comment: please post your code,where you ar getting value from textfiled

Comment: here it is.  None of that worked

Comment: these all codes are not in the same method i guess. you defined both int number and NSNumber * number. it must give an error for redefinition

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Once see this one,

```
NSString *string = @"123";
NSNumber  *aNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [string integerValue]];
NSLog(@"%@",aNum);//NSString to NSNumber
NSInteger number=[string intValue];
NSLog(@"%i",number);//NSString to NSInteger
```

Comment: I think it was the `numberWithInteger` and `integerValue` parts that made it work for whatever reason.  Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *string = @"54";
NSNumber *number = @([string intValue]);
NSLog(@"here we are: %i", number);
```

Instead try using the following:

```
NSLog(@"here we are: %@", number);
```

Since you are converting to NSNumber (Object). You should use object specifier %@ in your NSLog statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample with an integer and using NSNumber literals.  You could also use the `floatValue` method if your string contains a float.

```
NSString *string = @"54";
NSNumber *number = @([string intValue]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be, ***NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[string intValue]];***?

Comment: This uses NSNumber literals which amount to the same thing.

Comment: Oooopssss.  Use "%@" since it's an object. *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

@Aaron Wojnowski,

Use `NSNumberFormatter` If you want, you can set grouping separator also.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatString = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
stringValue = textfield.text;
NSNumber *reqNumber = [formatString numberFromString:stringValue];
```