# How To Convert UITextField value Into NSNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnumber

I've tried to convert the UITextfield Value Into a float first then convert it to an NSNumber but that doesn't seem to work as seen below.

```
       float carb = [self.carbGrams.text floatValue];
       NSLog(@"%.2f", carb);
       nCarbGrams = carb;
```

In the last line I get this error message:

Assigning to 'NSNumber *__strong' from incompatible type 'float'

I've then just tried assigning carb as an NSNumber by doing this

```
      NSNumber *carb = [self.carbGrams.text floatValue];
      NSLog(@"%.2f", carb);
      nCarbGrams = carb;
```

But I get this error message instead :

Initializing 'NSNumber *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'float'

As I've read I though NSNumber could accept any type of numeric value but I seem to be incorrect, can someone please evaluate the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an object of typ `NSNumber` from the float. As such

```
float carb = [self.carbGrams.text floatValue];
NSNumber *nCarb = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: carb];
```

or why not use the fancy (new) literal syntax

```
NSNumber *nCarb = @([self.carbGrams.text floatValue]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Objective-C literal syntax:

```
NSNumber *carb = @([self.carbGrams.text floatValue]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSNumber *carb = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.carbGrams.text floatValue]];
```

Comment: or with modern syntax `@([self.carbGrams.text floatValue])`