# NSString is a number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a TextField and wanted to know if the user just pressed numbers

eg::
_tfNumber.text only has numbers?

is there any function on NSString for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will let you know if all of the characters are numbers:

```
NSString *originalString = @"1234";
NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSString * trimmedString = [originalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:numberSet];
if ((trimmedString.length == 0) && (originalString.length > 0)) {
    NSLog(@"Original string was all numbers.");
}
```

Note that this ensures it won't give a false positive for the empty string, which technically also doesn't contain any non-numbers.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
NSCharacterSet *_NumericOnly = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *myStringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:mystring];

if ([_NumericOnly isSupersetOfSet: myStringSet]) {
    NSLog(@"String has only numbers");    
}
```

I got it from: http://i-software-developers.com/2013/07/01/check-if-nsstring-contains-only-numbers/

You can use this method in your `UITextField`'s delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and do the verification while the user is typing.

Comment: +1, because it's a creative solution, but keep in mind that this will give a false positive for the empty string, because any set containing anything is a superset of the empty set. Also, will `isSupersetOfSet:` return `YES` if the two sets are identical, or does the superset actually have to contain additional characters? Depending on that, it may return `NO` for a string containing all of the numbers.

Comment: I'm gonna try it in a while and make sure :) thanks @Gavin for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

No, but it should be easy to write:

```
- (BOOL)justContainsNumbers:(NSString *)str {
    if ([str length] == 0)
        return NO;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++)
        if (!isdigit([str characterAtIndex:i]))
            return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try regular Expression,

```
NSString * numberReg = @"[0-9]";

NSPredicate * numberCheck = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", numberReg];

if ([numberCheck evaluateWithObject:textField.text])
    NSLog (@"Number");
```

Comment: Won't this only evaluate true if it matches one number? Your regular expression doesn't match the beginning and end of the string, and also doesn't have repetition.

Comment: In fact I confirmed that this only matches when it's a single digit. So it will match the string "1", but not "1234".

Answer (score -2):

No.  `NSString` is not an `NSNumber` and any values you get from a `UITextField` will be an `NSString`.  See [THIS SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448875/585320) for converting that entered `NSString` value into an `NSNumber`.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, though I can see your confusion based on the title alone.

Comment: It absolutely does answer the question.  If the TextFields value is not a number (all digits), then the NSNumber from the formatter will be nil.  This method has the benefit of not only checking, but getting the value as well.  Please un-downvote.

Comment: No. I stand by my down vote as is. I read the question as: "How can I check if a string contains only digits?" This may exclude characters such as `-`, `e`, `E`, `.` which the linked question would accept. Given the question is a little unclear.