# Float value from Decimal Pad in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have UITextField with Decimal Pad and i want to convert it's value to float.

```
var myValue: Float = NSString(string: myTextField.text).floatValue
```

On my emulator i have no problems: in Decimal Pad i see numbers and "." so i can enter values like 123.45, but on device i have a problem because on decimal pad i see numbers and ",". So after adding "123,45" to myTextField i see that

```
myValue = 123
```

I know that i can change "." to "," in setting but i am really not sure about my app users.

So my problem is - how can i get float value from decimal pad not only with "." using Swift?

I see two kind of solutions: 
1) how can i config decimal pad to show "." instead of "," on any device? 
2) how can i convert to float strings with "," delimiter?

Comment: It would be better if you used the NSNumberFormatter class. By default it would take the encoding of the settings, so you wouldn't even need to set it up.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to write an example, just look for how to use the NSNumberFormatter. It's pretty easy.
If you can't find it out (I doubt it), I can write an example as an answer later on.
Good luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

Comment: @Volker there is solution for swift here? And maybe there is something about Decimal Pad settings?

Comment: The difference between Swift and Obj-C with NSNumberFormatter is marginal. One should be able to use the code within seconds...

Answer (score 4):

I have this snippet only in ObjC, but the answer is that you need to use an `NSNumberFormatter`, the problem is due to a difference in how `locale` is managed from the input to the inner float representation.

```
numberformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberformatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberformatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[numberformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

[Here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/formatting-numbers-nsnumberformatter-examples.html) more hints on how to use number formatters