# I cannot insert value with NSNumber datatype into my coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   attribute: property = "XXXXX"; desired type = NSNumber; given type =
>   NSTaggedPointerString; value = 0.'

Tried: [enter image description here][1]

```
 [message setValue:localID forKey:@"local_id"];
```

localID is of type NSNumber

DataModel image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WTlU.png

```
 [self insertInLocatDB:print_data entityName:@"Message_data" withPredicate:@"receiver_id" filterWith:@"unique_id"];
```

Using this to insert into CoreData:

```
 -(void)insertInLocatDB :(NSMutableArray *)arr_msg entityName:(NSString*)name withPredicate:(NSString*)predicateText filterWith:(NSString*)filterText
{
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:app.context];
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];
    NSInteger local_id =[self getMaxLocalId:name];


    for(int i=0; i<[arr_msg count]; i++)
    {
        [fetched_data removeAllObjects];
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ like %@ ",predicateText,[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:predicateText]];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matchingData=[app.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        local_id=local_id+1;

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            [fetched_data addObject:[obj valueForKey:filterText]];
        }
        NSString *filter=[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:filterText];
        if(![fetched_data containsObject:filter])
        {
            NSManagedObject *message=[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:app.context];
            [arr_keys setArray:[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] allKeys]];
            [arr_values setArray:[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] allValues]];
            [message setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
            for (int i=0;i<[arr_keys count];i++)
            {
                if( [[message.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]] != nil
                   && ([[[message.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]] isKindOfClass:[NSAttributeDescription class]]) )
                {
                    [message setValue:[arr_values objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
            [arr_keys removeAllObjects];
            [arr_values removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide more details?

Comment: Attribute local_id has datatype NSNumber in core data. I am trying to generate a local_id and insert that into CoreData

Comment: NSInteger local_id=local_id+1;
NSNumber *localID = @(local_id);

Comment: error itself telling the problem `Unacceptable type of value for attribute` `desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSTaggedPointerString`.

Comment: can u please see my above comment, converted it to NSNumber and then inserted it

Comment: Try using `NSNumber *localID  = [NSNumber numberWithLong:]`

Comment: Crashed and Reported same error

Comment: try type casting the string see this ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448875/4003548

Comment: the problem was converting NSInteger to NSNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a core data attribute as shown in my screen shot.

[image]

Then, the following snippet of code will work for you.

```
BOOL result;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"message"
                                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newMessage setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
    [newMovie setValue:movieName forKey:@"message"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    result = YES;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        result = NO;
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return  result;
```

and a function to get the managed object context

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

**Edited Code of Sandhya.**

```
-(NSInteger)getMaxLocalId :(NSString*)entitiyName
{
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entitiyName inManagedObjectContext:app.context];
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];
    NSInteger local_id = 0;
    request.fetchLimit = 1;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"local_id" ascending:NO]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    local_id=[[app.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error].firstObject integerValue];
    return local_id;
}
```

Then used the following to insert in to CoreData

```
NSInteger local_id =[self getMaxLocalId:name];
local_id=local_id+1;
[message setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
```

make sure you get the local_id.

As you have NSInteger, For conversion you should use `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` Instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]`

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
NSString *filter=[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:filterText];
if(![fetched_data containsObject:filter])
{
    NSManagedObject *message=[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:app.context];
    [arr_keys setArray:[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] allKeys]];
    [arr_values setArray:[[arr_msg objectAtIndex:i] allValues]];
    [message setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
    for (int i=0;i<[arr_keys count];i++)
    {
        if( [[message.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]] != nil
           && ([[[message.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]] isKindOfClass:[NSAttributeDescription class]]) )
        {
            if(![[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"local_id"]){
                [message setValue:[arr_values objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[arr_keys objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }
    [arr_keys removeAllObjects];
    [arr_values removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work kindly post your code in detail

Comment: And by mistake you have placed your code in answer section. Instead of that you should edit your question

Comment: [message setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
 i used this as well

Comment: Can you post your datamodel?

Comment: or just post the whole code that you are using. Its hard to get the idea

Comment: when i add the data type for local_id as NSString it works fine. But when the data type is NSNumber is throws error and crashes!

Comment: Ok, I think, I am close to solution now. Just update your datamodel from `interger 64` to `integer 32` .  And give it a try

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "local_id"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSTaggedPointerString; value = 0.'`

Same

Comment: does your `arr_msg` also contain local_id?

Comment: if yes, then while iterating please skip that. Other than this I don't see any issue.

Comment: Yeah... It Worked...Thankyou @Praful

Comment: @Sandhya if this answer helps you, you must accept this answer.

Comment: Great to hear that. Anyways as @Rajat said. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick. This will help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger)getMaxLocalId :(NSString*)entitiyName
{
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entitiyName inManagedObjectContext:app.context];
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];
    NSInteger local_id = 0;
    request.fetchLimit = 1;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"local_id" ascending:NO]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    local_id=[[app.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error].firstObject integerValue];
    return local_id;
}
```

Then used the following to insert in to CoreData

```
NSInteger local_id =[self getMaxLocalId:name];
local_id=local_id+1;
[message setValue:myNumber forKey:@"local_id"];
```

Comment: what `getMaxLocalId:name` is returning here ?

Comment: that will return the maximum value for local_id

Comment: [message setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] forKey:@"local_id"];
 crashes

Comment: try deleting and reinstalling app if you updated core data fields later ..

Comment: Did that several times.

Comment: when i add the data type for local_id as NSString it works fine. But when the data type is NSNumber is throws error and crashes!

Comment: and the error is exactly is same you have mentioned above `desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSTaggedPointerString; value = 0 ?`

Comment: check the returned value of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:local_id] ` using `isKindOfClass` method inside if else.

Comment: tell also the type of `local_id` `integer 16, 32, 64, Decimal, Double ...etc` ?

Comment: `local_id` `integer 32`

and i used that `isKindOfClass` it is of NSNumber only

Comment: okay, as i see the user praful has posted exact ans using `integer32`, make sure about the value you are trying to insert just double check.

Comment: `if([num isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            {
                [message setValue:num forKey:@"local_id"];

            }`