# check if the NSString is integer or double

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, integer, double

how can I check if the NSString *val I have has a Integer or float ?? The raw approach is to look for "." character..but is there a more graceful way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565696/nsstring-is-integer

Comment: @alex c: Not a duplicate, handles only a part of what the poster wants.

Comment: @DarkDust: I see what you mean; I assumed OP knew he had a number (either int or float) and merely wanted to distinguish.  I've posted an answer dealing with the general case.

Comment: **Never** check for `.` explicitly - many countries use `,` rather than `.` as a decimal separator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518761/get-type-of-nsnumber

Answer (score 8):

First, try [`[NSScanner scanInt:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanInt%3a)`&& [NSScanner isAtEnd]`.  If it returns `YES`, then you have an int.  `scanInt` will scan forward as long as it can interpret the stream as an int.  If `isAtEnd` is YES, then the entire string could be interpreted as an int (so you have an int).

Otherwise, try  [`[NSScanner scanDouble:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanDouble%3a).  If it returns `YES`, then you have a double.

If both return `NO`, then you don't have either.

Comment: Hmmm, the only problem with that is that for example the input `1` will have both methods return `YES`, as will `1.3` (AFAICS). In the first case both will return the same parsed numbers, but not in the second case. I guess one has to just use `scanDouble:`, if it returns YES, check whether the double is "integer", for example with `fmod(value, 1) == 0`. If that check says the number is integer, simply cast it to integer.

Comment: @DarkDust good point.  I believe you could also just use `[NSScanner isAtEnd]` after `scanInt`; if YES, then you have an int.