# Checking if NSString is Integer

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString is integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565696/nsstring-is-integer)

I'm looking to see if a string is ONLY numbers. Basically:

```
if (string is integer):
   #do whatever
else:
   #error
```

How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have used `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]`. Definitely works well.

```
NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
{
// newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, it doesn't work with decimal numbers :(

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)isANumber:(NSString *)string{
    NSPredicate *numberPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^[0-9]+$'"];
    return [numberPredicate evaluateWithObject:string];
}
```