# Check if the NSString in the UITextField is NaN

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am developing an iOS app and I want to check wether the string in the textfield is a `NaN`.
I am using the following code, I am calling this code inside button click:

```
int incrby = [self.valueField.text intValue];

if (isnan(incrby)) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Enter a valid number for the increment" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    [self.valueField becomeFirstResponder];
    return;
}
```

But the above code is not working.
By not working I mean if I enter a NaN value it does not show alert.

For eg: if I enter `hey` or `hey3` it should show alert

I dont want to make the textfield as number only (show numberpad only).

I searched and found some examples but could not solve my problem

I am new to iOS and don't know what to do what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565696/nsstring-is-integer ?

Comment: An integer value will never (can never) be a NaN as NaN is a floating point concept.  See @Larme's comment for some ways to validate numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as expected, because calling `intValue` on an `NSString` with non-numeric characters will return `0` (which *is* a number).

The following should do the trick:

```
// Remove any digits from the string to leave only letters & punctuation
NSString *lettersAndPunctuation = [self.valueField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];

// If there are any letters or punctuation, show the alert
if (lettersAndPunctuation.length > 0) {
    // Show alert, etc
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this way

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", output] isEqualToString:@"nan"]) {
```

}